# how to connect to server in remote domain with winrm

Tags: powershell, winrm

I have winrm enabled on a remote server and from a member of that server's domain, I am able to run Powershell commands using PSSession. However, from a client in another domain, I get "Connecting to remote server ... failed with the following error message : The connection to the specified remote host was refused.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (*server FQDN*:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException"

I did put the remote server into my client's TrustedHosts list. Here's an example command:

icm -comp *ServerFQDN* {dir} -cred *domainShortName\MyUserID*

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score -1):

The client in another domain must management rights.
Check this link: [Configure Windows Remote Powershell Access](https://helpcenter.gsx.com/hc/en-us/articles/202447926-How-to-Configure-Windows-Remote-PowerShell-Access-for-Non-Privileged-User-Accounts)

You may also to try to enable PSRemoting, if not enabled.

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

Take a look at this link: [Enable Powershell Remoting and WinRM](https://www.poftut.com/enable-powershell-remoting-psremoting-winrm/)

Comment: That does not appear to address the error that I'm getting. I'm using an administrator user when specifying credentials.